# Objective-C help NSTimer doesn't repeat

Tags: objective-c, timer, nstimer

i need a little help i have a method; countDown which is called when iTunes sends a notification, the method countDown then runs the method timerHit which gets a double minuses one from it then sets the value to a label, the method countDown is set to repeatedly run timerHit, however it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what i have so far, any help would be much appreciated.

```
- (void)countDown {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerHit:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerHit:(NSTimer *)p_timer {
    iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];

    if ([iTunes isRunning]) {
        double trackDuration = [[iTunes currentTrack] duration];
        trackDuration--;
        [duration setDoubleValue:trackDuration];
    }
}
```

Thanks, Sami.

Comment: From playing around with the code i have realised it does minus on from the value but then doesn't repeat and update the label.

Comment: Is this timer being scheduled on the main run loop, or in a thread of your own?  If the latter, is there an active run loop on this thread?

Comment: Is `duration` your label or something? Where is the code that is trying to update the label?

Comment: @NSResponser, sorry I didnt quite understand what you're asking, I'm a bit if a newb, also @raidfive yes duration is the label I'm trying to update, it gets updated once but then doesn't loop.

Comment: Is `[iTunes isRunning]` still being evaluated to `YES` after the first iteration? That would prevent that entire block from executing if not.

Answer (score 2):

If the timer is on a thread then you should run it on a active run loop like so:

```
NSRunLoop *mLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerHit:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

mRunLoop = YES;
while (mRunLoop && [mLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]]);
```